# A guideline to building angular apps based on npm and typescript

Tags: build, typescript, npm, angular

with the release of angular2 I actually encountered typescript, npm, ... for the first time, and I really appreciate its power, so I barely grasp the surface.

In the "development mode" I can find my way, but in the end:

### Question:

*I want to generate an independent folder that includes all necessary dependencies: js, css, html-files and is portable without needing npm, transpilers,... anymore. (So basically I want to copy this generated folder to a server and people can access the index.html as usually)*

### Problem

#### Setup

- npm (as a module manager and build tool) [npm as a build tool](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/), [npm as a build tool II](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-to-npm-as-a-build-tool/)
- typescript (tsc as transpiler)
- angular2 (with separated files for html, css), SystemJS

#### Needed Guideline

- An (abstract) guideline for what steps to take in order to achieve the prescribed goal, namely a folder that has (all) the features and is build from the typescript files, (probably .scss-files,...) in a separate and self-contained way.

*Probably I am searching for the wrong keywords but I have only found some fractions of my answers so far and I would really appreciate a list (of tutorials, or so) that I can stepwise go through. (Currently I feel lost)*

Comment: start from here https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html . where you feel problem ask question about that problem on SO

Comment: Thanks, however typescript and angular2 are not the problem. I think I have perfectly understood the quickstart and the other tutorials in the angular docs (and how to install modules with npm,...). The problem rather resides in going from the development mode (where npm knows about all file locations, lite-server is running, ...) to a fully self-consistent distribution folder with a newly generated index.html file and all needed css, html and js-files included and in the right location (thus I can move the folder wherever I want).

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the [systemjs builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder), using a build process such as [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) to configure the index.html, and consitute the build like this:

- build typescript files
- bundle js files using systemjs in the build folder
- build scss files (there must be a plugin for gulp) in the build folder
- copy all html files in the build folder
- inject dependencies in index.html

This is a raw answer to your question, untested, and from the top of my head, but I hope it can lead you to a solution. I have a little something in [this repository](https://github.com/Ledragon/bar).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer goes into the direction I was looking for. Do you know if there is an automated way taking care of the last two steps? (I have not yet the permission to upvote your answer, sorry)

Comment: you could copy files using gulp, doing something like `gulp.src('app/**/*.html').pipe(gulp.dest('build/')` and inject the dependencies using gulp-inject.